# Como lograr que servidor de aplicaciones web sea en único que tenga acceso al servidor de servicios web

Tags: webservice, aplicación-web

favor su colaboración con lo siguiente (imagino que es algo clásico que muchos lo saben, :( pero yo no)

Escenario: Tengo un servidor de servicios web llamado serverws, y otro de aplicaciones web llamado serverapp, obviamente el serverapp consume los servicios de serverws, todo funciona correctamente.

Problema: Cualquier usuario puede ver el serverws, y con SOAPUI u otra herramienta ejecutar cualquiera de los metodos de los web services

Interrogante: Como hago para que solamente el serverapp tenga acceso al serverws?

Nota. No puedo hacer a nivel de red ya que existen limitaciones por el Hardware.

Estaba pensando en algo de certificados, pero no se nada al respecto.

Bueno me quedo atento a comentarios y/o sugerencias de todos, agradecido de antemano me despido.

Comment: no puedes simplemente restringir la ip, de tal forma que el servidor web solo acepte peticiones de el servidor de apps

Comment: Jejejeje parece algo simple, una pregunta al respecto, se puede permitir el  mas de 1 ip (por ejemplo 5)? si es que si podrías explicarme como se lo hace???

Comment: Si podrías para 5, el problema es que no has dado especificaciones de los servidores ni sus configuraciones. solo dijiste que tienes 2 servidores

Comment: Son Windows Server 2016 con su IIS por defecto, el servicios web es wcf SOAP.

Comment: Bueno lo primero que encontré y funciono es mediante IIS, con esto:

http://www.maxilovera.com.ar/blog/hosting-y-servidores/iis-7-permitir-una-ip-bloquear-todas-las-otras/

Pero me agradaría saber mas opciones

Comment: Efectivamente esa es una forma de hacerlo